# "sh: /usr/local/bin/node: not found" while it is present on the Filesystem

Tags: node.js, docker, file-not-found, docker-multi-stage-build

After switching from `bullseye-slim` to `bookworm-slim` Docker image I experience `env: can't execute 'node': No such file or directory` error and it looks like it is caused by `COPY --from=1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sonarqube:latest / /`.

**Here is what I see on the container:**

```
~ # ls -l /usr/local/bin/node
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      92350992 Oct 13 14:02 /usr/local/bin/node
~ # /usr/local/bin/node
sh: /usr/local/bin/node: not found
```

The file is there, but cannot be executed as it is not found

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as base

WORKDIR /usr/src
EXPOSE 8080

COPY .npmrc /usr/src/
COPY package*.json /usr/src/

# --------------> The develop image
FROM base as develop

ENV NODE_ENV=development

RUN npm ci
COPY . /usr/src/

# --------------
FROM develop as develop_sonarqube

COPY --from=1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sonarqube:latest / /

# --------------
FROM base as dependencies
RUN ...
```

If I build it targeting `develop_sonarqube` stage (this is where copy is), I get `sh: /usr/local/bin/node: not found` error when invoked with `docker run --rm foo:baz npm run format`

But if I target `develop` and run it, there is no error:

```
> foo@0.0.1 format
> prettier --check .

Checking formatting...
[warn] package-lock.json
[warn] package.json
[warn] Code style issues found in 2 files. Run Prettier to fix.
```

So it seams like `COPY --from=1234567890.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sonarqube:latest / /` is a culprit, but it happens on `bookworm-slim` base image only meaning that if I change it back to `bullseye-slim`, it will work.

Any ideas how to fix it?

**Debug info:**

```
# ldd /usr/local/bin/node
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f000494b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f000494b000)
Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/node)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f000494b000)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/node)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f000494b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x7f000494b000)
Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/bin/node)
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt7getlineIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_istreamIT_T0_ES7_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS4_S5_T1_EES4_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE9pbackfailEi: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt19__throw_logic_errorPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __once_proxy: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt17__throw_bad_allocv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6xsgetnEPcl: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIyEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZdlPvm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt6locale7classicEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _Znwm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: fcntl64: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt10_Sp_lockerC1EPKv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5imbueERKSt6locale: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo5tellpEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5closeEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base7_M_hookEPS0_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: gnu_get_libc_version: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_demangle: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7copyfmtERKS2_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7_M_syncEPcmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSolsEi: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt16__throw_bad_castv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_guard_acquire: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4initEPSt15basic_streambufIcS1_E: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZdaPv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIlEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE3strEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: backtrace_symbols: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIbEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt20__throw_system_errori: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt9use_facetISt5ctypeIcEERKT_RKSt6locale: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZStrsIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEERSt13basic_istreamIT_T0_ES7_RNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS4_S5_T1_EE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _Znam: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIPKvEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt11_Hash_bytesPKvmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt5ctypeIcE13_M_widen_initEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_decrementPSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo5writeEPKcl: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo5flushEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base11_M_transferEPS0_S1_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertImEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSolsEs: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt12__basic_fileIcED1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5imbueERKSt6locale: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZdlPv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo3putEc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekoffElSt12_Ios_SeekdirSt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_guard_release: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE7seekposESt4fposI11__mbstate_tESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSi10_M_extractIdEERSiRT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt20__throw_length_errorPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt20__throw_out_of_rangePKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __popcountdi2: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5rdbufEPSt15basic_streambufIcS1_E: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __register_atfork: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE9showmanycEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt18condition_variableD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_baseD2Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy11_M_next_bktEm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt6localeC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt10_Sp_lockerD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6xsputnEPKcl: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEEC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt18condition_variableC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt28_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erasePSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseRS_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo5seekpElSt12_Ios_Seekdir: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE9underflowEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_incrementPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: setcontext: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __cxa_pure_virtual: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt18condition_variable10notify_allEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8__detail15_List_node_base9_M_unhookEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __dynamic_cast: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_incrementPSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt16__ostream_insertIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_PKS3_l: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_baseC2Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt6localeD1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy14_M_need_rehashEmmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_lockISt5mutexE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt12__basic_fileIcE7is_openEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: makecontext: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5uflowEv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNKSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5widenEc: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_decrementPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt29_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalancebPSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseS0_RS_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt25__throw_bad_function_callv: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE5clearESt12_Ios_Iostate: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEC1ESt13_Ios_Openmode: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: backtrace: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: getcontext: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE6setbufEPcl: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZNSo9_M_insertIxEERSoT_: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt11__once_call: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt15__once_callable: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt7nothrow: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1115basic_stringbufIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTNSt7__cxx1119basic_ostringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt15basic_streambufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTNSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTSt14basic_ifstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: __libc_stack_end: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt9basic_iosIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTTNSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZTVSt13basic_filebufIcSt11char_traitsIcEE: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt4cout: symbol not found
Error relocating /usr/local/bin/node: _ZSt4cerr: symbol not found
```

Comment: What exactly is in `/usr/local/bin/node`? Some platforms will display this error if it has a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) with an incorrect path (i.e. `#!/usr/bin/sh` when you only have `/bin/sh`).

Comment: I'm vaguely speculating that the binary has unresolved dependencies or perhaps was compiled for the wrong architecture.

Comment: it is a bin file without shebang. wrong arch should not be the case as there is single host machine

Comment: What's the output of `ldd /usr/local/bin/node`?

Comment: Shared objects required info added to the ticket

Comment: Yes, great catch! Do you think I need it on a host or container?

Comment: If the error happens in the container then that's where it's missing from. I would imagine your host would be smoked if it had this kind of problem, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for including the `ldd` output. It clearly tells you what's wrong. The `/usr/local/bin/node` binary depends on shared libraries which are missing from the target system.

https://packages.debian.org/ lets you search for file names (scroll down to "search package contents" near the bottom); generally you want to skip everything after `.so` in the search when looking for shared libraries.

The search results (linked below) are kind of intimidating. You want to ignore all the cross-compilation stuff; my money would be on the below list, but ideally the people you got the binary from should be able to give authoritative information.

- [`libgcc-12-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgcc_s.so&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) ... or maybe `libgcc-11-dev` or etc
- [`libstdc++-12-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/search?mode=path&suite=bookworm&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B.so) ... or maybe `libstdc++11-dev` or etc

There could be additional downstream problems if you resolve these two, so you may get a new error and then need to iterate over that.

Comment: I soled it by reinstalling node/npm and as it is Alpine based image we need apk: `RUN apk add --update nodejs npm`